# ServiceStack basic authentication

Tags: servicestack

I'm fairly new with ServiceStack authentication bit. First I configured basic authentication:

```cs
private void ConfigureAuth(Funq.Container container)
{
    var authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() }
    );
    authFeature.IncludeAssignRoleServices = false;

    // Default route: /auth/{provider}
    Plugins.Add(authFeature);

    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
    container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(GetAuthRepository());
}
```

1. How to authenticate with a service request? for example:
    `myweb/api/auth/basic?Userid=test@Password=234`
2. The authentication service endpoint in protected itself. calling `myweb/api/auth/basic?Userid=test@Password=234` will redirect `/Account/LogOn`

I need a very simple authentication mechanism. Clients can simply authenticate by sending a JSON request.

Answer (score 2):

See [ServiceStack AuthTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AuthTests.cs) for examples on how to authenticate with Basic Auth.